# find a file in a directory based on size, user, and owner

Tags: terminal, find

I'm using a [cheat sheet](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-find-command-to-search-for-files-based-on-file-size) on how to find a file based on size where I am looking for a file 33 bytes in size. What if I have lots of directories and lots of file. Is it possible to loop through all directories and `find` a file 33 bytes in size owned by user `bandit7` and group `bandit6`?

Not a lot of wisdom here... This gets me file size of 33 bytes but just curious on how to combine with owner:

`find . -size 33c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you search for is:

```
find . -size 33c -user bandit7 -group bandit6
```